# current column width in a tabu table

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabu

Is there some way of getting the current column width in a tabu table in the same way that one can refer to `\columnwidth` in a multicol?

For example, the following gallery works but its a bit ugly since the column content had to know its width.  i.e. we had to specify `[width=.45\textwidth]` whereas we would prefer not to have to do that.  If this were a multicol then we could have just used `[width=\columnwidth]` in its place.

I searched through the tabu documentation looking for all occurrences of `width` but did not find it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{XX}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{myfig}} &
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{myfig}} \\
Some text.  & Some more Text.  \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's documented, but you can always refer to the current width of a parbox by `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{XX}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{myfig}} &
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{myfig}} \\
Some text.  & Some more Text.  \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Just say `\linewidth` instead of the complicated `\dimexpr...\relax` if you don't want the frame.

Of course the `\linewidth` would change in a nested `list` based environment; in this case you can always use `\hsize` (this is surely undocumented).

Comment: Thanks. Accepted. I don't understand the part about not wanting the frame. Both   `\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{myfig}}` and `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{myfig}` seem to work.

Comment: @user1189687 The first will give an "Overfull `\hbox`" message because of the padding around the figure to leave space for the frame.